# Font looks a little bolder on chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser

Its weird, when I use Source sans pro it looks bolder on chrome but when I switch to safari it looks thinner.

I have Source Sans downloaded so I don't have it embedded in the head

Not sure if its my code or my browser
heres a piece of text in my code

```
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">MY WORK</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ABOUT ME</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
ul{
font-family:'Source Sans Pro';
left: 50%;
position: absolute;
font-weight: 100;
letter-spacing: 0.5px;
font-size: 13px
```

}

Comment: Well, you've just discovered the age-old issue of cross-browser compatibility

Answer (score 14):

Try this it might help:

```
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; /*(For Firefox)*/
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /*(For Chrome and Safari)*/
```

Comment: Just a hint, author forgot to add `-` at the beginning for there vendor prefixes. Should be: `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;`

Comment: This made my day! Thank you so much!

Comment: Wow thanks, been 2 years I was wondering why Figma and Chrome designs were looking different!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to Font style:

`backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one. I think it's helpful:

```
:focus, a:focus {
    outline: 0
}
```